# Simpler possibility for groupedview

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a problem. I want to write an Windows 8 application and think that a Grouped GridView, like in the Sample Grouped Items App Template contained in Visual Studio, would be a good choice for data representation.
But I have problems in understanding how this works (I mananged to modify the contained `SampleDataSource`, so that my content is shown). The problem I have is, that there are many elements and I can't determine what element causes what.

So my question:

Can anyone explain (or provide a link to) how I can build such a Grouped GridView from scratch?
The Sample Template is not that helpful, because it is a little bit confusing (4 classes in one file and sometimes a little bit strange construction).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to see a simple example explaining CollectionViewSource and GridView, right?

Comment: @kimsk I think he also wants an explanation of the SampleDataSource and the DefaultViewModel(s) used in the built-in App templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the basic requirements for using a Grouped GridView are:

(Note: all class names are arbitrary)

- A ViewModel (You're using Mvvm, right?)
- A Group object which holds the elements of each group.
- An Item object which the Group will contain a collection of
- A View with which to display the items which includes a GridView and a CollectionViewSource (including any styling for the Groups and Items)

An example group and Item:

```
public class Group<T> where T : Item
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

An example ViewModel:

```
public class GroupsViewModel : ViewModelBase // This implementation uses Mvvm Light's ViewModelBase, feel free to use any
{
    public ObservableCollection<Group<Item>> AllGroups { get; set; }

    public GroupsViewModel()
    {
        AllGroups = new ObservableCollection<Group<Item>>();

        Group<Item> group1 = new Group<Item>();
        group1.Title = "Group 1 Title";
        group1.Add(new Item(){ Value = "The first value." });
        AllGroups.Add(group1);

        Group<Item> group2 = new Group<Item>();
        group2.Title = "Group 2 Title";
        group2.Add(new Item(){ Value = "The second value." });
    }
}
```

On your Page, create a CollectionViewSource in your Page.Resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding AllGroups}"
                            IsSourceGrouped=True
                            ItemsPath="Items"
                            x:Name="GroupedCollection"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Notice that the Source is bound to the `Collection` of `Group`s, and the `ItemsPath` tells the `CollectionViewSource` that the set of `Item`s in each `Group` at that Property.

Your `GridView` will reference this. It is important that you set the items source like below. An empty `{Binding}` with the `Source` set to the `StaticResource` of the `CollectionViewSource`. You can style each group in the `GridView` using the `GroupStyle` kind of like such. I stripped it down to be *incredibly basic*. The default sample you already have will have a better example.

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedCollection}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
            >
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
</GridView>
```

Lastly, you'll have to set the `DataContext` of your `Page` to the `ViewModel`. If you're using Mvvm Light, it will be something like `DataContext="{Binding GroupsVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`. You'll need to do some further setup obviously to get that to work. You can also just set it in the `Page` constructor.

```
public MyGridViewPage()
{
    DataContext = new GroupsViewModel();
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Works nearlly perfect, but how can I avoid, that one element is selected automatically (when all elements load, one is selected by default)?

Comment: If you want there to be no ability to select from the `GridView`, then `SelectionMode="None"`. If you want it to just deselect everything on load, then you can add a `Loaded` event and set the `GridView`'s `SelectedItem` to `null`, `SelectedIndex` to `-1`, or call `SelectedItems.Clear()`.